Switching 12V 50A with Arduino
I'm in the middle of building a DIY Powerstation with a 500W modified sine wave inverter. The battery is of type LiFePo4 and rated at 12.8 50Ah. The datasheet of the battery states that they recommend a low voltage cutoff at 10V. My current setup is, among other things, an Arduino Nano that monitors the voltage of the battery with a voltage divider. I'd like to disconnect the inverter by using the microcontroller. I've already searched the internet for relays or MOSFETs rated for such currents, but I had a hard time grasping the datasheets. Is it possible to switch such currents with an Arduino, if yes, what components can I use?
EDIT: The maximum continuous discharge current is also 50A

50Ah is battery life time not maximum current.

If the inverter has a disable input, you could use that. 500 W at 12 V is 42 A, maybe 50 or 60 with losses. There are more MOSFETs that can handle those sorts of current than you can shake a stick at if you look on the proper component supplier sites like Mouser or Digikey. Sort the list of FETs by continuous drain current.

@Lundin I edited the question, the max continuous discharge current is also 50A.

@Neil_UK Thank you, I will. How large is the heat emission of such MOSFETs? Do I have to use heatsinks?

It depends on the RDSon, which is a parameter you can also sort on. It will dissipate I^2 * RDSon, which may or may not need a heatsink, check the datasheet, though an unnecessary heatsink is the better way round to have an error. Make sure you look at the RDSon for your gate voltage, no point driving a FET with an RDSon specified at 10 V gate voltage with 3.3 V on the gate - it will switch on softly and dissipate much more than you expected. So look for 'logic level' FETs which can be driven OK with 3.3 V, or drive your gate at 12 V via a transistor.

Hint, low voltage FETs tend to have much lower RDSon than high voltage ones, because physics.

@Neil_UK There are a lot of FETs like this one https://www.tme.eu/gb/details/irlp3034pbf/tht-n-channel-transistors/infineon-technologies/ that would match voltage and current requirements, but I'm pretty sure that either the terminals or the transistor would instantly burst into flames with 50A at 12V.

@Patrick That FET would be just fine. 1.7mohm RDSon max means 6 watts dissipation at 60 amps. It will need a heatsink, but need not be huge. Tjc is 0.44C/W, so the junction only gets 3 C hotter than the case. Those leads are good for 75 A. If you're using a board, make sure any copper traces have at least that area. The gate is good for +/- 20 V, so drive it to 12 V, RDSon goes up at 5 V, and there's no spec for 3.3 V. You're pretty sure something will burst into flames? These things are surprisingly tough, when driven correctly. Drive it correctly.
